# How to find command history of Swift REPL

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I've been typing commands into the Swift REPL (on macOS), and rather than scroll back to view my command history, I'm wondering if there's a file or database that saves the history like in other REPLs (e.g. python) that I can look at.

Is this available?

Comment: @Martin R: But you can access entries from earlier sessions in the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift REPL (which actually starts the lldb debugger in a REPL mode)
uses *libedit* for command line editing and history. On exit, the history is saved to the file `~/.lldb/lldb-repl-history` 
(compare [SR-4338 Swift REPL crashes on launch if `~/.lldb/lldb-repl-history` contains emoji](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4338)).

It should not be too difficult to figure out the history
file format from the libedit source code. Here is a simple example.
After the REPL session

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let a = 1
a: Int = 1
  2> let b = 2
b: Int = 2
  3> print(a + b)
3
  4> ^D
```

the history file contains

```
_HiStOrY_V2_
let\040a\040=\0401\012
let\040b\040=\0402\012
print(a\040+\040b)\012
```

Comment: I guess my next question is how can we translate it into a readable format, but thank you!

Comment: @WillB: I do not know which libedit macOS uses, but here is one version of history.c: http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/lib/libedit/history.c?rev=1.57&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN. One can see that the C library functions strvis/strunvis  are used to escape/unescape the input lines. Whitespace is replaced by a octal escape sequence.

Comment: There have been several requests to "save" the current REPL session.  Most requests want something that is actually a valid swift file, which is pretty difficult since you can do all sorts of things (redefine classes, etc.) that are not legal in swift files.  Those requests have stalled...  But a simple "dump the text I've typed in in this session" command should be fairly straightforward to implement.  Feel free to file an enhancement request for this at bugs.swift.org, or if you are feeling adventurous, try hacking it in yourself!